# How can I repair this washing machine that I think has had the chip wiped?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have been having a huge problem with my washing machine and I think that it's because the chip program is wiped or a problem with the EEPROM.

Here's [a video](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=A7A774340EBDCCAA!1780&authkey=!AEWvVyl4Opwf-hU&ithint=video,.mp4) showing what happens when I plug it in the wall, until I unplug it:

I have already sent the control panel to be fixed, 2 tracers were burned and are now repaired but still the problem persists.

Does anyone know what the problem is and what the fix might be?

The following is a picture showing what was burned before I sent it to the repair shop:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RolEdYX.jpg]

And here is the view from above:

[image: i.imgur.com/gETfuKX.jpg]

The parts in the burned tracers area are a M10LZ47 5-J (or 5-i, don't recall correctly) screwed to the heatsink and a small 104 smd capacitor.

I can't find a replacement anywhere so my only choice is to repair whatever the problem might be so I am trying to see if someone here might give me a hand.

Comment: Answerers might like to know this repair Q was previously asked on [apliantology.com](http://appliantology.org/topic/46178-samsung-bigwash-q1044-spins-to-max-rpm-and-buttons-dont-respond/) then on [electronics.se](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/94103/2191) and put on hold there (so not a candidate for migrating back there)

Comment: The Toshiba SM10LZ47 is a "BI−DIRECTIONAL TRIODE THYRISTOR SILICON PLANAR TYPE" for "AC POWER CONTROL APPLICATIONS" rated at 5W peak 0.5W average, 800 Vdrm, 10Vfgm, 10A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to leave an update, I replace the PCB with another from a completely different model that had AG+.

I thought it wouldn't work at first because I didn't have the Silver Nano extra pcb and for my surprise it did work so if anyone is having the same problems of finding a replacement for their model then find one that is the equivalent of yours and it will work.
I don't know if the same is possible with the dryer versions so only try with those if you have absolutely no other choice.

My washing machine is a Q1044, portugal model - original PCB model is MFS-Q1044-00 - and the PCB that I used for replacement is from the Polish (or russian, I am not quite sure now) model F1245AV - PCB model MFS-1245A-00.

All connections fit perfectly and everything works well, except for the Silver Nano technology which I wouldn't want either way.

Answer (score 2):

Later versions of this assembly are potted so that cockroaches can't cause the sort of catastophic short-circuit shown in the question.

[image]

Samsung service/repair manuals and schematics are [available from 3rd parties](http://www.manualsparadise.com/service-repair-manuals/Samsung/WF7602S8R-YLP-WF7602S8RYLP/RWSPFM-17864953-1)

Comment: Hi, Red, only a few other models have it potted and my model only has that version made so I'm stuck with it. I have already tried that website but when I paid the money there was no download link for my model and I am now stuck in a refund proccess.
As you were able to see, I am trying to find any help that I can to see if I can get the one I own fixed because I can't find any replacement.